# Switching order of integration in double integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Unfortunately, I could not find another article which explained this. I'm not sure how switching order of integration works properly

Consider the following double integral:
$\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_x^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin y}{y} \mathrm dy \mathrm dx$
Now intuitively I would think that we'd sketch the region and we'd get that it's bounded by $y=x, \pi/2$ and also for x by $0, \pi/2$. Now if we switched our order or integration we would attain $\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^y \frac{\sin y}{y}\mathrm dx \mathrm dy$
Now my understanding of this seems very flawed for the reason that this doesnt make full sense to me... Are we looking at rotating the graph by 90 degrees and then kind of "treating" our $x$ as our new $y$ in a sense? This is difficult for me because if we do so then I'd think that we're looking at it backwards so I'm not entirely sure where this goes. Is there a way to properly visualize changing the limits of our integrals?

Comment: Read up on Tonelli's Theorem.

Comment: oki ill do that then